# FindViewById() don't working in a Main Activity.cs

Tags: android, xamarin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want access to "Resource.Id" in Main Activity.cs , but when I write the code follow :

```
 $Button button = Findviewbyid <Button> (Resource.)
```

I can't access to "ID" , Why !! and How?

Comment: try `$Button button = Findviewbyif <Button> (Resource.Id.your_id)` or 

`Button button = activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.recordbutton);`

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I'm sorry , I'm wrong, i

Answer (score 0):

Resources are compiled into "R", not "Resource". You need to do:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: amacf " The name R does not exist in the cureent context"

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that you are using Xamarin. The Resouce file should be created automatically. Have you tried running a "Clean and Rebuild"?

Comment: Ok , Thank u very much my friend, to help me